# How many times does the line $y=\frac{1}{4} x$ cut the curve $y=\sin(x)+\cos(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, periodic-functions

This is a multiple choice question, where using calculators is not allowed. Candidates have, on average, two minutes to solve the problem.

PROBLEM:

> How many times does the line $y=\frac{1}{4} x$ cut the curve $y=\sin(x)+\cos(2x)$?

CHOICES:

> (A) $4$ (B) $5$ (C) $6$ (D) $7$ (E) $8$

---

What I have tried was not feasible:

- Using differentiation, I found that the curve is bounded between $y=\frac{9}{8}$ and $y=-2$.
- When $x<-8$, $\frac{1}{4}x<-2$ , and when $x>\frac{9}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}x>\frac{9}{8}$. So, any solution to the equation $y=\sin(x)+\cos(2x)=\frac{1}{4}x$ must lie in the interval $(-8,\frac{9}{2})$.

I do not know how to proceed from these two points. Even I know, that takes a long time.

Also, I do not know if using the fact that the curve is periodic will really help.

---

By Desmos, I took a look to the graph, the line cuts the curve $7$ times. So the correct choice is $D$.

---

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: To solve this within 2 minutes is difficult indeed

Answer (score 3):

This answer does not pretend to be rigorous but just suggests an approach to solve the problem in two minutes (you need a peace of paper and a pencil).

You have already almost done the job. The function is periodic with period $2\pi$ and has on this period two minima $(\frac\pi2,0),(\frac{3\pi}2,-2)$
and two maxima: $(\arcsin(\frac14),\frac98),(\pi-\arcsin(\frac14),\frac98)$.

Now just draw a picture, putting on the plot approximate positons of maxima and minima and connecting them with straight lines. We know that  $\arcsin(\frac14)\approx\frac\pi{12}$, but in fact the value does not matter as the figure tells you!

The only doubt is about the leftmost intersection and it is resolved by observing
$$
-8<-\frac{5\pi}2\iff \pi<\frac{16}5.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The function is periodic with period $2\pi$ and achieves local extrema

$$y' = \cos x - 2\sin 2x = 0 \implies \cos x (1-4\sin x) = 0$$

at

$$\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}+2\cos^2x-1\Bigr|_{\cos x = 0} = 0,-2$$

and

$$\sin x + 1-2\sin^2x\Bigr|_{\sin x = \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{9}{8}$$

which means the only interval we can expect intersections is on $\left[-8,\frac{9}{2}\right]$. The function has four extrema per period and the interval contains

$$\frac{25}{4\pi} = \frac{8\pi+(25-8\pi)}{4\pi} = 2 + \epsilon$$

two whole periods by estimating since $\epsilon < \frac{1}{12}$. $2\cdot 4 = 8$ turn arounds means $7$ intersections between them.

Comment: If the minima at $\frac\pi2+2\pi n$ were a bit lower or a bit higher your answer would be wrong.

Comment: @user sure but that's just due to poor phrasing on my part to emphasize how to think about this problem quickly. Really what I meant was $$\frac{25}{4\pi} = \frac{8\pi+(25-8\pi)}{4\pi} = 2 + \epsilon$$ where $\epsilon < \frac{1}{12}$. None of the extrema occur within $\frac{1}{12}$ of a period inside of the end points, but this would take too long to verify within the time constraint of the problem. A student would have $2.\cdots$ where $\cdots$ is a small number in their head, and a well designed test would not allow edge cases like that with the time constraint.

Comment: I still do not understand. Assume the functions are $x/8$ and $\sin x+\cos^2x$. What would be the answer in this case?

Comment: @user the interval in this case would be $[-8,10]$. The function is still $2\pi$ periodic so the interval contains $$\frac{18}{2\pi} = 3 - \epsilon$$ where $\epsilon <\frac{1}{6}$ but do you not see how this is unsuitable for such a test? $\frac{1}{6}$ is too large a chunk of the period to make any reasonable estimations about what goes on within those of the endpoints.

Comment: I do appreciate you taking the time to respond to me and even come up with new parameters to test when most people reading this probably ignored it. But it is not that I didn't understand your point but rather you are not understanding mine. Being rigorous about this is not the goal, it is about being mostly (but crucially, not 100%!) confident with estimating an answer.

Comment: I just wanted to understand the logic behind your answer but I did not succeed. For me drawing the curve with known maxima and minima would be much simpler and faster way to find the critical points where the linear function has to be evaluated.

Comment: @user How would you draw it accurately and evaluate something like $\sin(8)$ numerically without a calculator in an efficient (< 2 min) manner?

Comment: Without any problem (and I did it in less than 1 minute). One does not need to calculate $\sin(8)$. One needs only to know that the function is monotonic between the maxima and minima. In the given example it suffices to connect the neighboring extrema simply by straight lines (as well as the endpoints of $x/4$).

Comment: @user That would be a better answer than mine! I like geometric explanations over algebra. Would you care to post it? Edit: wait a second that's exactly what I said. What makes your answer more confidently correct/rigorous?